# Trouble with nested rails classes & routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-class

I'm trying to get back into rails after a while and am having a tough time connecting two simple scaffold-built resources in a nested fashion. The parent controller works, but the child usually blows up. I've been looking all over for an answer to this problem, but haven't succeeded.

For a specific comment child belonging to a product parent, route "/products/1/comments/1"

**Error message**

> Couldn't find Comment without an ID
>   app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:25:in `show'
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"product_id"=>"1",
>   "id"=>"1"}

**Here's the relevant code from comments_controller "show"**

```
def show
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@comment = @product.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
```

(If I change :comment_id to just :id the new error is:)

> Couldn't find Comment with ID=1 [WHERE (`comments`.product_id = 1)]
>
> {"product_id"=>"1",
>   "id"=>"1"}

**For comment index: /products/1/comments**

**Error info:**

> undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class
>   Parameters:
>   {"product_id"=>"1"}

** Relevant code from index view **

```
18:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', [@product, comment.id] %></td>
19:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_comment_path(@product, comment) %></td>
20:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [@product, comment], :confirm => 'Are you sure?',           :method => :delete %></td>
```

I've spent a couple days messing with this to no avail. Been checking simple things like :id to :(noun)_id as well as switching between [@product, comment] and [@product, comment.id] in my view links.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated on how to get this working. It seems like it should be simple, and I pretty much followed the "book." The trouble with this is that my rails texts (The Rails way and a little ruby intro book with a couple chapters on rails) are based on rails 2 at best, and web resources haven't been entirely updated.

**Updates:**
**Routes.rb**
    Party2::Application.routes.draw do

```
resources :comments

resources :products do
  resources :comments
end
```

**Errors from comment index**

> undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class

**Relevant code from comment index (Error at line 18)**

```
18:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', [@product, comment.id] %></td>
19:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_comment_path(@product, comment) %></td>
20:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [@product, comment], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

**Another update:**
**Models**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Thanks again,

Cameron

(Seems very strange to me that this shouldn't work, as I've been following tutorials. :/)

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from router.rb please?

Comment: Updated post with route info and error. Thanks for looking, @Ant & @Harald.

Comment: Hmmm, your routes and controller code look fine to me, could you post the relevant bits of your models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a comment can belong to only one product, you should be able to do something like this in the comments_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  # @product = @comment.product
end
```